# Противительно-пояснительные отношения между частями бессоюзного предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Будьте любезны, восполните пробел в моем образовании, скажите, какой знак препинания ставится между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, вторая часть которого одновременно и противопоставляется первой, и поясняет ее: "Это не так [а так]:/- ..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы здесь поставила двоеточие:В действительности это не так (Что именно не так? Почему не так?):  сериал «Дневники вампира» намного более жесток и реалистичен". Здесь нет точного противопоставления типа "ноги носят - руки кормят" или "все за одного - один за всех". Здесь больше раскрывает содержание, поясняет или содержит причину, почему не так, но не противопоставление.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, я не совсем поняла Ваш вопрос. Поясните его,  например, на следующем примере:

"На первый взгляд может показаться, что сюжет «Дневников вампира» очень похож на «Сумерки». В действительности  это не так - сериал «Дневники вампира» намного более жесток и реалистичен".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

В связи с последним сообщением Noir , я позволю себе небольшое лирическое отступление. Во-первых, меня всегда волновал вопрос,  почему для выбора трех основных знака препинания (запятой, тире, двоеточия) нам требуется  90 правил пунктуации.Не легче ли каждому знаку приписать одно-два обобщенных значения.

Во-вторых, я часто вспоминаю замечательное высказывание К.Паустовского:"Знаки препинания - это как нотные знаки, они твёрдо держат текст и не дают ему рассыпаться". Это на письме, а в устной речи текст "держит" интонация. У нас удивительный язык - мы не говорим, а поем, и знаки препинания должны не практике служить нам "нотными" знаками. Вот вы пишете текст, вкладывая в него определенные мысли, и надеетесь, что читатель правильно поймет вас. И знаки препинания должны не столько соответствовать  90 формальным правилам, сколько отвечать за смысл содержания и красоту формы.

В нашем примере второе предложение явно поясняет первое, а значение пояснения успешно передают два знака - тире и двоеточие. Двоеточие соответствует подчеркнутой паузе, в случае тире пауза слегка обозначена. Есть область, где эти знаки практически равноправны, тогда это авторский выбор, учет  ритмики всего текста. Но есть варианты, где выбор тире или двоеточия приближается к однозначному. Только двоеточие ставится при наличии слов, требующих пояснения, например: "это надо сделать так..." или "надо помнить об одном... ". Можно назвать это "обязательным пояснением". А тире ставится в том случае, когда мы имеем "свободное пояснение" - можем продолжить это предложение, а можем перейти к следующему.

В нашем примере мне хотелось бы оставить тире не только из-за такой свободы, но и из-за пропуска части текста: это не так (а вот как). А тему пропуска однозначно выражает тире, так что здесь оно выполняет двойную работу.

Comment: Вы все верно поняли, и Ваш выбор примера это подтверждает